# Price calculator doesnt works after a ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my price calculator doesnt works after a ajax call. I hope someone can help me.

ajax call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#bundesland_products').change(function(){
            var url = '/inc/products_new.php?id=' + $(this).val();
            $('#products').load(url);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Price calculator

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.option').on('click', function() {
        var total = 0;
        $('.option:checked').each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).attr('price'));
        });
        $('#total').html(+total+',00 EUR');
    });
});</script>
```

HTML

```
<div>Gesamtpreis: <strong><span id="total">0,00 EUR</span></strong></div>
```

Comment: you may need to post some more code.

Comment: Assuming the `.option` elements are dynamically appended to the DOM using `load()` then you need to use delegated event handlers.